# Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: apache, xampp

I hitting my head against a brick wall.

I set up a program (it was updating about 200k rows in the database) in PHP on XAMPP to run and it was there running for about 8 hours and then I think it crashed or something hence in the log (this was on Friday):

```
[Fri Apr 25 21:49:55.816100 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5632:tid 256] AH00428: Parent: child process 6948 exited with status 1073807364 -- Restarting.
```

I come into work today and Apache wont run!!!! My programs were trying to be forced closed.

I've tried changing ports to 8080 and 4430 and 7777 and it wont work. Ive changed Skype so it doesnt use port 80 and looked for programs using por 80 and nothing

Please help me guys to solve this it appears that nothing is working

Thanks

Comment: Stop hitting the wall with your head. Denting walls is a serious crime these days.

Comment: This has nothing to do with port usage (why do you say skype uses port 80??). You have to find out what "status 1073807364" is, then you have your reason.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error. Now I have to do this process everytime I restart my machine

Go into command prompt (Start->type in "cmd")
Type the following:

`net stop was /y`

Restart Apache services and it should work.

It will stop Windows Process Activation which for some reason blocks the standard XAMPP port.